# Cloud Functions: Checking if email exists in users document in Firestore not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a Cloud Function which is adding Admin privileges to a user. I got this to work, but when I tried to add a layer of error handling (so that an exception would not occur when an email is passed in that is not a registered user) I didn't get this to work, and after scratching my head for several hours I still can't figure it out.

What's happening is that this code always return `null`, and I think maybe it has something to do with the result from **checkIfUserWithEmailExists** is never turning `true`.

This is the code that I created:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();

exports.addAdmin = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const result = await checkIfUserWithEmailExists(data.email);
  if (result === true) {
    if (context.auth.token.admin !== true) {
      return {
        error: "Request not authorized. User must be an admin to fulfill"
      };
    }
    const email_1 = data.email;
    return grantAdminRole(email_1).then(() => {
      return {
        result: `Request fulfilled! ${email_1} is now an admin`
      };
    });
  } else {
    return {
      error: "No user with this email was found"
    };
  }
});

async function grantAdminRole(email_2) {
  // get user and add custom claim (admin)
  const user = await admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email_2);
  if (user.customClaims && user.customClaims.admin === true) {
    return;
  }
  return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {
    admin: true
  });
}

//Checks that the email passed in is an existing user
async function checkIfUserWithEmailExists(email) {
  const userCollectionRef = admin.firestore().collection("users");
  userCollectionRef
    .where("email", "==", email)
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      if (querySnapshot.size === 1) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not properly awaiting the promise in your check function. Try this:

```
//Checks that the email passed in is an existing user
async function checkIfUserWithEmailExists(email) {
  const userCollectionRef = admin.firestore().collection("users");
  const querySnapshot = await userCollectionRef
    .where("email", "==", email)
    .get();

  return querySnapshot.size >= 1;
}
```

In general it can be confusing to combine async/await with Promise `.then()` so I try to avoid doing so.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, worked flawlessly! :)

Comment: @MichaelBleigh why no `await` before `admin.firestore().collection('users')`?  Is it because nothing is being called on that path?  i.e. you are not `get()`ing or `set()`ing it, so it's just acting as a shorthand to that path, not a server call?

Comment: Correct, `collection('collName')` just creates a [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference) which is a shorthand to the collection, not an actual server call.